# Calling .net dll method from Java

Tags: java

I am trying to call .net dll method by using jni4net jar. The dll is loading, the proxy folders are generated but while executing getting the below error.
[image]

The code error is attached.

Comment: Please post the error as _text_, not as an image. Generally the more effort _you_ put into your questions (take a look at help and the FAQ) the more people will be able and willing to help.

Comment: It will not help you but calling the code from the finally block is a weird idea: if the dll loading failed it will be executed and you will get a énd error.

Comment: Here is the error :   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: mathfunc.ClsMathFunc.__ctorClsMathFunc0(Lnet/sf/jni4net/inj/IClrProxy;)V
 at mathfunc.ClsMathFunc.__ctorClsMathFunc0(Native Method)
 at mathfunc.ClsMathFunc.<init>(ClsMathFunc.java:25)
 at com.java.Test.main(Test.java:41)

Comment: I removed the finally block, still throwing the same error.                                                                                                                Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: mathfunc.ClsMathFunc.__ctorClsMathFunc0(Lnet/sf/jni4net/inj/IClrProxy;)V

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the javadoc of [UnsatisfiedLinkError](http://the%20answer%20is%20in%20the%20javadoc%20:%20https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html%20the%20JVM%20can't%20execute%20your%20code)

The JVM can't execute your code because the virtual machine don't kwehow to execute some natives commands of your dll